# SharePoint 2010 CHOICE value-attribute unknown?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, field

following [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439235.aspx) a CHOICE Element in a field declaration for SharePoint should have a Value attribute.

> Value
>
> Optional Text. Specifies the display
>   text for the choice.
>
> The value can be a reference to a
>   resource in the format
>   $Resources:String. However, choice
>   values are not supported by the
>   multilingual user interface (MUI).
>   Choice values are initialized in the
>   default language of the web site and
>   do not change when a user switches to
>   an alternate language supported by the
>   site.

My current implementation looks like the following and doesn't work:

```
<CHOICES>
      <CHOICE Value="Offen">open</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE Value="Duplikat">duplicated</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE Value="In Bearbeitung">inprogress</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE Value="Nicht vorhanden">unavailable</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE Value="Erledigt">finished</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
```

VisualStudio 2010 claims, that no schema information for this attribute is found.
Has Microsoft forgotten to implement this or do I understand something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Not surprising that MS has contradictory documentation. I also see on the same page, under "Remarks", this: *"The CHOICE element contains the value within its body."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439235(v=office.12).aspx

> Reading this, you might be led to
>   believe that you could create a
>   CHOICES collection like this to have
>   SharePoint use value codes on the
>   back-end of its DropDownList's options
>   tag in HTML. Like this:
>
> Maryland Delaware Virginia Pennsylvania
>
> Well, you'd be wrong. In fact, as
>   nearly as I can tell, the Value
>   attrbiute of this element does nothing
>   at all. It's not invalid if you use
>   it; it doesn't break anything; it just
>   doesn't do anything. And, the
>   documentation leads you to believe
>   that it should, which I think has the
>   potential to cause a huge waste of
>   time.
>
> If you want a value that is different
>   than the text, here's the right way to
>   do it.
>
> MD#;Maryland
>   DE#;Delaware
>   VA#;Virginia
>   PA#;Pennsylvania
>    MD
>
> Originally posted as a blog-rant at
>   http://thomascarpe.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26.
>   I'll update mine if you update yours.
>   :-)

Thanks to Doc WattsMan for this explanation!

Comment: Outch this is also wrong. The truth is: It is not possible. Answer from an Moderator of the Microsoft social Network: The documentation is wrong since SP 2007.